# unable to pull secrets or registry auth: execution resource retrieval failed: unable to retrieve secret from asm

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-secrets-manager, aws-fargate

My configuration :

- Fargate
- Private subnet
- NAT gateway
- Task execution role  contains `AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy` and Inline policy :

  ```
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
          {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                  "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"
              ],
              "Resource": [
                  "arn:aws:secretsmanager:region-x:XXXXXX:secret:secretname-string",
                  ....
              ]
          }
      ]
  }
  ```

When I use Fargate 1.3, It's OK.

But for 1.4 for **same configuration** (private subnet, nat gateway, policies, Security groups, ...) I have this error : `ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: execution resource retrieval failed: unable to retrieve secret from asm: service call has been retried 5 time(s): failed to fetch secret arn:aws:secretsmanager:region-x:xxxxxxx...`

I must use 1.4 version of Fargate because I need use EFS.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The support response working for me:

> Check the VPC endpoints for secret manager. It is having the security group: "sg-xxxxxxx" and this Security Group is not having inbound port 443 allowed. So create a inbound rule to allow  port 443 for x.x.x.x/xx (CIDR of VPC).

Comment: Wow, I was searching forever and knew the NAT was working, but this was the hidden problem I didn't even know I needed to deal with.

Comment: Why would you need a VPC endpoint if you are using a NAT gateway?

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly this error (pasted in again with some additional text to catch more Google searches):

```
Resourceinitializationerror: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: execution resource retrieval failed: unable to get registry auth from asm: service call has been retried 5 time(s): failed to fetch secret arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:#########:secret:secret/name from secrets manager: RequestCanceled: request context canceled caused by: context deadline exceeded
```

I had messed up the security group by mixing up inbound and outbound rules; I had no inbound rules, and only 1 outbound rule on port 8080.

Once I fixed up the security group to allow all outbound traffic, the task was successfully started.